# Connect sql server via jdbc with two different server names

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I have two server names on my sql server. One is the localhost, the other is the localhost\SQLEXPRESS. Now I want to connect to the localhost but not the localhost\SQLEXPRESS. I could connect to the localhost\SQLEXPRESS via jdbc with             `String connectDB="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;DatabaseName=TPCH";` successfully. While I have tried change "localhost\SQLEXPRESS" to "localhost", tried change some port number "1433" but both not work. How to figure this out?

Comment: If you have two instances of SQL Server running on the same machine then they cannot both be listening on port 1433. And, in fact, specifying both the instance name and the port number is redundant and potentially confusing, especially since it is highly unlikely that the \SQLEXPRESS instance is actually listening on port 1433. Try `jdbc:sqlserver://(local)` and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks Gord. I think your point that port number and instance name are redundant makes sense. I make a new instance "A" and find its port number then everything works well. This issue has confused me for a long time. Last time I have also tried different port numbers, but not succeed.The thing is the new instance "A" I created has its port number. And the "localhost\\SQLEXPRESS" also has its port number 1433. While the "localhost" doesn't have one port number. Actually I have three instances now but I could find only two port numbers. Now the thing works well but I am also curious about this.